# PyQuery for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyquery

So according to [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) here PyQuery is "Python3 compatible", but I can't find any information about how to actually install it, since it still seems to be dependent on setuptools which is python2.x only.

I also tried to newest source from bitbucket that contains a bootstrap-py3k.py but that fails just as well - actually it just seems to download setuptools into a tmp dir and trying to run that.. which will fail for obvious reasons.

But still I assume I should be able to do whatever setuptools is doing manually as well if the lib itself is already python3 compatible, or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), which is a drop-in replacement for setuptools and has py3k support.

Comment: Great, that worked. Thanks! And an extremely useful library that is at that - working out of the box as a drop-in replacement.. that's what I call comfort :D

Comment: @Voo: It's a fork. It is essentially Setuptools but it is being maintained.